# PySpark: extract values from from struct type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe where one of the columns (called `features`) is a struct type, specifically:

```
struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>
```

When I do `df.printSchema()`, this is what I get:

```
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

What I would like to do, is to have the `values` of the above struct in a separate column.

I have tried:

```
df.select("features.values").show()
```

But then I get the error:

```
AnalysisException: Can't extract value from features#125369: need struct type but got struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>;
```

Which I don't understand, especially the part where it says `need struct type but got struct` (??). Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to convert the vector to array first:

```
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array

df2 = df.select(vector_to_array("features").alias("features"))
```

and then select the appropriate columns.

Comment: Hi @mck, thanks for your answer. I tried this function, but I seem to be getting a different array than the one in the `values` array of the `features` column. Here's an example of 1 row: the `values` array of `features` contains this: `[1, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1]` but the "new" features (after applying `vector_to_array`) contains: `[1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Do you know why this is not the same array? I can't seem to find any good documentation on this function.

Comment: @vdvaxel that’s strange, but I can’t say anything without seeing some code

Answer (score 0):

To complete @mck answer, if you use Pyspark < 3, you need to use an UDF that converts the vector to a list and then applies the type (array of floats):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

to_array_udf = F.udf(lambda vector: vector.toArray().tolist(), T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))

df2 = df.withColumn("features", to_array_udf("features"))
```