# How can extract date from struct type column in PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm dealing with PySpark dataframe which has `struct` type column as shown below:

```py
df.printSchema()

#root
#|-- timeframe: struct (nullable = false)
#|    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
#|    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

So I tried to `collect()` and pass `end` timestamps/window of related column for plotting issue:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# method 1 
ts1 = [val('timeframe.end') for val in df.select(date_format(col('timeframe.end'),"yyyy-MM-dd")).collect()]

# method 2
ts2 = [val('timeframe.end') for val in df.select('timeframe.end').collect()]
```

So normally when the column is not struct I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51911920/10452700) but in this case I couldn't find better ways except this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844357/how-to-convert-dataframe-columns-from-structvaluedouble-to-structvaluesarra) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65185952/pyspark-extract-values-from-from-struct-type) which they tries to convert it to arrays. I'm not sure this the best practice.

What I have tried 2 methods as shown above unsuccessfully which outputs belows:

```py
print(ts1)     #[Row(2021-12-28='timeframe.end')]
print(ts2)     #[Row(2021-12-28 00:00:00='timeframe.end')]
```

Expected outputs are below:

```py
print(ts1)     #[2021-12-28]          just date format
print(ts2)     #[2021-12-28 00:00:00] just timestamp format
```

How can I handle this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.html) fields using brackets (`row["field"]`) or with dot (`row.field`) not with parentheses. Try this instead:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(timeframe=Row(start="2021-12-28 00:00:00", end="2022-01-06 00:00:00"))])

ts1 = [r["end"] for r in df.select(F.date_format(F.col("timeframe.end"), "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("end")).collect()]
# or
# ts1 = [r.end for r in df.select(F.date_format(F.col("timeframe.end"), "yyyy-MM-dd").alias("end")).collect()]

print(ts1)
#['2022-01-06']
```

When you do `row("timeframe.end")` you actually calling the class `Row` that's why you get those values.